# Get Application Path

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, path

Ok, I am moving a few of my Winform projects from Framework 4.0 to Framework 4.5 and I am running into a problem trying to find the Executable path from a Class Library. I have an error logging class that I use to log errors here is a snippet of my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FunctionClassLibrary
{
    public static class ErrorLogging
    {
        public static string errLogFullPath
        {
            get
            {
                string errLogFile = "Application";
                m_errLogFullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), errLogFile + "_ErrorLog.txt");
                return m_errLogFullPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I am able to reference the System.Windows.Forms namespace which in turn exposes the Application.ExecutablePath property. Apparently in Framework 4.5 you can no longer reference System.Windows.Forms namespace. I have been googling all morning with no success, these two MSDN links: [LINK1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) and [LINK2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath.aspx) both show examples using the System.Windows.Forms namespace. So my question is does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

## **Update**

Ok, I am losing my mind, I just realized that I can simply use the Environment.GetFolderPath method to find the CommonProgramFiles folder, which is where I should be storing this file anyway. Sorry to bother everyone this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                 errLogFile + "_ErrorLog.txt");
```

Or:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                 errLogFile + "_ErrorLog.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),errLogFile + "_ErrorLog.txt");
```